# Easy (?) DTFT calculation

Tags: discrete-signals, dtft

I'm asked to compute the DTFT of the following signal but i'm quite stuck

$$
\begin{cases}
(-1)^{\frac{n}{2} + 1} & \text{ if } n \text{ is even} \\
0 & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd} 
\end{cases}
$$

Here where I am, i'm starting by using the definition of the DTFT

$$
\begin{align}
X(e^{j\omega}) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n]e^{-j\omega n}\\
&= \sum_{n \text{ even}} (-1)^{\frac{n}{2} + 1} e^{-j\omega n} \\
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^{\frac{2k}{2} + 1} e^{-j\omega (2k)} \quad (n = 2k, k \in \mathbb{Z}) \\
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^{k + 1} e^{-j\omega (2k)} \\
&= - \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^{k} e^{-j\omega (2k)} \\
&= - \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} (-e^{-2j\omega})^k
\end{align}
$$

and here i'm stuck because I don't see how to compute the last sum... can someone help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is your signal causal? i.e, is x[n] = 0 for n < 0? Then the answer is simply an infinite geometric series sum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series)
1/(1-exp(-2j\omega))

Comment: @orchi_d: This won't work, even if all terms were zero for $n<0$, since the magnitude of the summands is not less than unity.

Comment: That is true, it would only work if if there was a term less than 1 multiplying the exponent. This sum does not converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

Try to rewrite the given signal as

$$x[n]=\pm\cos(n\omega_0)\tag{1}$$

with the correct sign and some appropriate $\omega_0$. Then you can just use the well-known identity for the DTFT of a cosine.

Note that the sum you're trying to compute doesn't converge in the conventional sense.

Comment: Thanks ! It works well :)

Answer (score 0):

This periodic function has a [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series).

$$ \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(t-n) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{j 2 \pi k t} $$

where $\delta(\cdot)$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) and we're playing a little fast-and-loose with the expression of $\delta(t)$ outside of an integral.

variations in scaling:

$$ T\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(t-nT) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{j 2 \pi k t/T} $$

$$ \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(f_0t-n) = f_0\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{j 2 \pi k f_0 t} $$